# cakephp website with phpBB or simple machines forums possible?

Tags: cakephp, integration, forum, phpbb, smf

I have a website made with CakePHP 1.3.7. This website has it's own login system. Now the client wants to include a forum in the website.

I've been looking at different free solutions and phpBB and SMF seem to be what I'm looking for. The only thing I'm not so sure is about integrating those forums with the login system that I already have.

I mean, if a user has already an account for the website (or creates a new one), he/she should be able to use that same account (username) in the forum section.

Is that possible? Any clue pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated! I mentioned both forum solutions in case one is easier to integrate than the other one, that would be also good to know (or if there's any other better option).

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: [Might be worth a look](http://blog.4webby.com/posts/view/2/smake_smf_cakephp_integration) it's quite outdated though.

Comment: Here is a CakePHP forum plugin: https://github.com/milesj/cake-forum

Comment: OK thanks! I'll check those out

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up using: [this](http://github.com/milesj/cake-forum)

It has all that I needed and integrates perfectly into Cake :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use both but I personally prefer SMF. You have to configure CakePHP's session component to use database sessions and create a model that will use the forums session table.

You can decide if you want or need a separate users table besides the forums users table (or its called members, don't know right now).

The "hard" part is to make the cake app read/write the sessions and cookies in the same fashion SMF does to allow a smooth transition from the cake app to the forum and backwards.

Technically you can use both forums and archive your goal with both, it's just a matter of getting the frameworks components utilized right.